# wicket ajax indicator

Tags: ajax, wicket, busyindicator

I have this situation:

I have an `IndicatingAjaxButton`. In the `onSubmit` method some operations get done and then the `setResponsePage(otherPage);` is called

While the operations are still in progress the busy indicator is visible. But then when the operations are done the indicator is gone while the user is still on the same page, capable of doing other activities, while the browser is busy opening the other page.

My question is how to make the indicator still visible as long as the browser is busy opening the `otherPage.`

Thank you

Comment: i don't understand well, but you could make visible the indicator with JS regardless of the state in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'd need to make sure you really need to do this in an ajax request. I wouldn't see it necessary unless you're doing `setResponsePage()` only depending on certain conditions, and else performing some Ajaxy operation.

If you don't need Ajax, I'd recommend dropping it and just sending a regular request. You can code a busy indicator client or Wicket side and make it show with javascript (maybe in `body.onunload` for a general way?).

But, if you really want to achieve this, you should understand why the indicator is being hidden. Wicket prepares the javascript that will be executed upon call completion (success or failure). The relevant method is [`AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior#generateCallbackScript()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.7/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java#AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.generateCallbackScript%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
final CharSequence onSuccessScript = getSuccessScript();
final CharSequence onFailureScript = getFailureScript();
...
if (!Strings.isEmpty(indicatorId))
    {
    String hide = ";wicketHide('" + indicatorId + "');";
    success = success + hide;
    failure = failure + hide;
}
```

Here Wicket is preparing the javascript `wicketHide(id)` call that will effectively hide the indicator once the request is completed (and upon sucess or failure).

I've never tried to do this, but probably overriding `getFailureScript()` and `getSuccessScript()`, to make the script `return` before executing `wicketHide(id)`, in your Ajax behavior should do the trick:

```
protected CharSequence getSuccessScript() {
    String script = super.getSucessScript();
    return (script != null ? script : "") + ";return false;";
}
protected CharSequence getFailureScript() {
    String script = super.getFailureScript();
    return (script != null ? script : "") + ";return false;";
}
```

Notice this would always leave the indicator shown, and never hide it. If you wanted to conditionally hide it or not depending on if a `setResponsePage` is done or not, you could, for instance, define a js variable by means of `AjaxRequestTarget`, and `return` conditionally in your `getSucessScript()` and `getFailureScript()` implementations.

Wicket's sources are (at least for me) amazingly clear to read and understand. They can help you lots at understanding how it really works and how can you tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if this solution works for me because the only this that goes wrong is that the indicator goes invisible while the page is still busy opening the other page. So I don't know how getSuccessScript() and getFailureScript() can help me. What I need is somehow let the indicator go on while the browser is busy opening the other page.

Comment: Overriding `getFailureScript()` and `getSucessScript()` to make the javascript `return` before executing `wicketHide(id)` will help avoiding to hide the indicator. If the indicator doesn't get hidden, it will stay on until the next page loads. But, if you only want to show the indicator when leaving the page, you might as well just add a javascript `onunload` event handler on `<body>` and show the indicator then.